# CSS Selector, apply CSS every 2 divs

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a problem targeting divs in CSS.

My code is like this:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="test">Asdasdasd</div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="test">Asdasdasd</div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="test">Asdasdasd</div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="test">Asdasdasd</div>
</div>
```

Here why I want to do: apply some CSS but only to the first and third "test" divs (or 5th if there are 6 card divs).

I tried to use `:nth-child(odd)` but without success.

Comment: To be perfectly selective in case you add non-`.test` content inside your `.card` divs, use `.card:nth-child(odd) .test {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you didn't apply it correctly try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7xmkav6c/)

```
.card:nth-child(odd){
color:green;
}
```

```css
.card:nth-child(odd){
    color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="test">Asdasdasd</div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="test">Asdasdasd</div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="test">Asdasdasd</div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="test">Asdasdasd</div>
</div>
```

## EDIT

If you want to apply it to the `test` try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7xmkav6c/1/)

```css
.card:nth-child(odd) .test{
    color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="test">Asdasdasd</div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="test">Asdasddfdfsvxcvasd</div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="test">Asdasdasd</div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="test">Asdasdasd</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks ! Yes I think I applied it to test instead of card

Comment: @drizo you are welcome you can do it with test too if you use the second method

Comment: yeah thats what I wanted to do, apply my CSS to test. Thanks a lot again !